# How to return non-empty top row column values of unknown column length in Excel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

Python version: 3.6
Python library: openpyxl
Excel version: 365

This will return the values from each cell in 255 columns of the top row of an excel file. I only put 255 in as a temporary place to stop:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=255, max_row=1, values_only=True):  
     print(row)
```

I don't know how many columns with data will be in each workbook.  All the top row cells that contain data will be consecutively listed starting from column 1.

When a top row cell without data is encountered, all remaining columns/rows will be empty.

I need the values of those consecutive top rows that contain values.

Thanks for the time.

Comment: Just go through the resultant tuple with an enumator and stop at the first `None`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @CharlieClark.  I'll update my findings, but if you want to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CharlieClark pointed me in the right direction.  Something like this worked out for me. I still had to keep max_col=255 though or it would error out.

```
def column_get():
    i = 1
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=255, max_row=1, values_only=True):
        for x in row:
            if row[i] is not None:
                print(row[i])
                i += 1
            else:
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can just remove max_col value. then it prints the first row values until an empty cell.
try this:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1, values_only=True):  
     print(row)
```

If you still see many None values check if the sheet's first row doesn't contain any value interpeted by mistake as None. I would suggest you to debug it this way: create a new empty sheet and insert manually a test data - see if it works. if it does copy paste manually the data from the actual sheet to the test one.

Comment: Yeah, you'd think that, but I got 487 entries of "None" after doing that.

Comment: @ArkhamAngel weird. I just tried it before I answered and it worked.
I tried it on Python 3.8.1 openpyxl 3.0.7

Comment: @ArkhamAngel Are you sure you sheet's first row doesn't contain any value interpeted by mistake as None? I would suggest you to debug it this way: create a new empty sheet and insert manually a test data - see if it works. if it does copy paste manually the data from the actual sheet to the test one

Comment: I'll try it out and hopefully remember to come back and update.

Comment: Row widths depend a lot on the structure of the worksheet, which is stored as a kind of sparse matrix but is best thought of as always being 16,384 cols wide an around a million rows long.

Comment: @tomer my list entries all had ${ in their strings.  I suspected that might be an issue.  I removed them along with max_col=255.  It ran normally as you described.  Thanks for your time everyone.

Comment: @ArkhamAngel happy to hear that :)
so if you don't mind, can you please mark my answer as verified?